# How to paste out each cell of column interText into input box at specific interval?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my html code, where i want to past each cell of specific column into input box of html code. I am able to get past out only last row column cell into the input box with id =**"selectedId"** but now each cell sequence wise in interval. My code is below, I am new to html if possible please help me....
Thanks in advance...

```js
var table = $("table tbody");

table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
    productId = $tds.eq(0).text(),
    product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
    Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();
  // do something with productId, product, Quantity
  const interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#selectedId').val(productId)
  }, 5000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="selectedId" type="text" />
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>63</th>
      <th>Computer</th>
      <th>3434</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Stationary</td>
      <td>111</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Stationary</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```js
var table = $("table tbody");
var idx = 0;
var $rows = table.find('tr');
const interval = setInterval(
  function() {
    if (idx >= $rows.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return
    };
    var $tds = $rows.eq(idx).find('td'),
      productId = $tds.eq(0).text(),
      product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
      Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();
    $('#selectedId').val(`${productId}, ${product}, ${Quantity}`)
    idx++;
  },
  3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="selectedId" type="text" />
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>Computer</td>
      <td>3434</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Stationary</td>
      <td>111</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Stationary</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```